# Is there any way to specify a color in PIL (for drawing a polygon) without an error?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

**Edit**: This is completely rewritten for clarification and to focus on just the issue I've encountered:

I download a satellite photo, in png format from the web.  I save it, then reload it in a PIL Image object.  No matter what, when I try to specify a color so I can draw a polygon on the image, PIL crashes.

This is where I load the image and try to draw on it:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor, ImageDraw

PILimage = Image.open(pngfile)

allpoints = coordinates16.split(',');
allpoints = [int(n) for n in coordinates16.split(",")]

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(PILimage)
draw.polygon(allpoints, fill=None, outline='red')
PILimage.save(pngfile, "png")
```

(coordinates16 is a comma separated string of a number of (x,y) coordinates, so I split it into a list of integers.)

When I use this code, if I do not specify any outline color for drawing the polygon, things work okay.  But when I do specify a color, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../HalPy/LandSearch/GetOurLotMap.py", line 140, in <module>
    getmap(latitude, longitude, defaultmapfile)
  File "../HalPy/LandSearch/GetOurLotMap.py", line 122, in getmap
    draw.polygon(allpoints, fill=None, outline='red')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 236, in polygon
    ink, fill = self._getink(outline, fill)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 145, in _getink
    ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 62, in getcolor
    self.palette = map(int, self.palette)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x06'
```

That last value, in the last line ('\x06'), is the same, even when I specify different colors.

Note that in the comments, from my first version, @Aankhen points out there is a [bug in PIL](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-2009-raclette/issues/14/valueerror-when-opening-png-file) with PNG files.  While the bug specifies it occurs when opening a PNG, it happens in the same function within the library.

With that in mind, I figured it should work better with another format, so I made a change to my code.  I saved the PNG file as a BMP file, then reloaded it as a BMP file:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor, ImageDraw

PILimage = Image.open(pngfile)
PILimage.save(bmpfile, "bmp")
PILimage = Image.open(bmpfile)

allpoints = coordinates16.split(',');
allpoints = [int(n) for n in coordinates16.split(",")]

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(PILimage)
draw.polygon(allpoints, fill=None, outline='red')

PILimage.save(pngfile, "png")
```

Note the change by adding two lines after the 2nd line.  After opening the PNG file, I immediately save it as a BMP file.  Then I reload it as a new object, now in BMP format.  After that, I do the same thing as before, hoping to avoid the bug.  I run it and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../HalPy/LandSearch/GetOurLotMap.py", line 140, in <module>
    getmap(latitude, longitude, defaultmapfile)
  File "../HalPy/LandSearch/GetOurLotMap.py", line 122, in getmap
    draw.polygon(allpoints, fill=None, outline='red')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 236, in polygon
    ink, fill = self._getink(outline, fill)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 145, in _getink
    ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 62, in getcolor
    self.palette = map(int, self.palette)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x02'
```

Again, the value at the end does not change when I change the color I specify for the outline.  (Although I note it is a different value from when I use a PNG format.)

Is there any way I can specify a value for the outline without getting an error?  I don't mind converting formats (but I was avoiding converting to any lossy format), but my main concern is it just seems impossible to specify a color without an error.

I'd even be glad to use a different library.  All I need to do is draw a polygon on a PNG file.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: The error message mentions `outline = `blue'`, which doesn’t show up in the code you’ve provided. Are you sure that’s where the issue is?

Comment: Here’s an old bug report I found: https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-2009-raclette/issues/14/valueerror-when-opening-png-file

Comment: I think @Aankhen may be right, that it's a bug.  And I copied an error message from an earlier run.  I tested it with different colors.  No matter what color, the same value, '\x06', was given on the last line of the error.  I did convert the image to a bmp, then try the manipulation, but still had trouble.  I'll be rewriting the question to clarify what I'm asking and removing most of the code.  The problem comes down to one line of my code, so I think the rest of it is not relevant.  (Or at least the parts that don't deal directly with PIL aren't relevant.)

Comment: What version of pillow are you using?  It works fine for me with v5.1.1 (under both Python2 and Python3).  Draws a red polygon on the image with no errors.

Comment: @OregonJim: I'm using PIL, not Pillow.  For some reason, even though I used pip to install Pillow, it simply won't import.

Comment: PIL was last updated in 2006!  Pillow has LONG since replaced it.  You do realize that the import names are identical to the old PIL ones?

Comment: I believe if you uninstall PIL and then install Pillow, it will "just work".

Comment: I uninstalled PIL and Pillow and, in IDLE, tried, "import PIL," just to see if it was all gone.  It imported PIL.  So there's some kind of path and priority issue here.  I'm on macOS and I think I remember a problem like this previously, so I'm going to have to check notes and see if Apple does something about prioritizing which libraries in which paths are used first.

Comment: Apparently this is one of the problems that has come up with Apple's SIP (a security feature).  I can use pip and install most modules, but it seems I can't override a module that is already installed.  The pip version of PIL is a recent version, the one Apple has installed is 1.x (don't remember the exact version number).  I've tried a number of combinations with PIL and Pillow and can't change a thing.  I'll be posting a question about that in the Apple SE site.

Comment: Verified now - yes, the problem is with SIP working, Apple makes it a mess to try to install modules with pip that basically replace existing modules that were part of the default install.